# Present a form to user on Windows login

Tags: forms, kiosk, limited-access

I have a public computer lab where users must give a few short details about themselves such as their age and objective before they use the computers. Currently this information is gathered by a lab attendant on paper.

I would like for the user to be given a form in Windows at the beginning of his or her session on a computer in the lab. It should be impossible to use the computer without filling out and submitting this form.

I am confident in my abilities as a web application developer and I would prefer to collect the data in some sort of browser-based form. How do I present it to the user and lock them out of Windows until it has been submitted?

Comment: I'm also open to solutions that aren't web-based as long as the learning curve isn't too steep.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a super limited user account which serves only to force people to signup (all they can do is open a web browser that allows them to access only 1 website).

It probably wouldn't log them off automatically, but they wouldn't be unable to do anything else in that user account.

Many kiosks are setup like this... very restricted user account that can't do anything except browse 1 domain (e.g. the store's website). They have a blank desktop and just a shortcut to internet explorer, and the browser denies them access to menu bars etc. and only works on 1 domain.

I would look at how people setup kiosks with windows and work from there...